# How to use different onKeyDown in fragment of a same activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, onkeydown

I want to use different onKeyDown or onKeyUp in different fragment,but the method is written in the activity.So I want to find a way to write different onKeyDown.

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic So I need some static variables as I switch some fragment in another fragment of the activity

Comment: no. check my answer. variables work fine too, but it makes the design ugly

Comment: Yeah,it is really ugly so I don't want to use this method.Fortunately,I think your method is pretty good,and I'll try it soon.Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FragmentManager`'s `findFragmentById()` to check what fragment is currently displayed, and `switch` for the fragment inside the `onKeyDown` function

Comment: I'm sorry to trouble you.But if I use a class to generate a fragment,how could I set its id or tag?Thank you~

Comment: In that case, when you call the `transaction.add()` or `transaction.replace()` method, add a third string argument which represents a tag for the transaction. 

From google documentation:

`public abstract FragmentTransaction add (int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)`

`tag - Optional tag name for the fragment, to later retrieve the fragment with FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String).'

Comment: It's very appreciate of you.But when I use FragmentManager's findFragmentByTag(),it needs a tag of String variable.So what I get from findFragmentByTag() is the fragment which I set in the variable.And in fact ,I want get the fragment which is currently displayed.

Comment: for that you need to keep a local variable (enum type, maybe?) to keep track of the current fragment, and for each value of this variable (thus, for each fragment) an associated String tag.

I have used this approach myself two days ago. There is no other way of getting the current view. Not one that I know of, at least, or not as easy as this one.

Comment: Ok,then I'll try it.Thank you !